# I have an issue during the build process with Rust cross-compilation using Cross

Tags: rust, build, cross-compiling

I got this error when building my app using cross :
(I can build it with cargo, no problems)

```
penwing@calcifer:~/Documents/projects/rust/susuwatari$ cross run --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
   Compiling libdbus-sys v0.2.5
error: failed to run custom build command for `libdbus-sys v0.2.5`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/target/debug/build/libdbus-sys-53211ac73c5c2cab/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build_vendored.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DBUS_1_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DBUS_1_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DBUS_1_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  pkg_config failed: 
  pkg-config exited with status code 1
  > PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1 dbus-1 >= 1.6

  The system library `dbus-1` required by crate `libdbus-sys` was not found.
  The file `dbus-1.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
  The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.

  HINT: if you have installed the library, try setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing `dbus-1.pc`.

  One possible solution is to check whether packages
  'libdbus-1-dev' and 'pkg-config' are installed:
  On Ubuntu:
  sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev pkg-config
  On Fedora:
  sudo dnf install dbus-devel pkgconf-pkg-config

  thread 'main' panicked at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/libdbus-sys-0.2.5/build.rs:25:9:
  explicit panic
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `libdbus-sys v0.2.5`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/target/debug/build/libdbus-sys-53211ac73c5c2cab/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build_vendored.rs
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DBUS_1_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DBUS_1_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=DBUS_1_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  pkg_config failed: 
  pkg-config exited with status code 1
  > PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1 dbus-1 >= 1.6

  The system library `dbus-1` required by crate `libdbus-sys` was not found.
  The file `dbus-1.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
  The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.

  HINT: if you have installed the library, try setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing `dbus-1.pc`.

  One possible solution is to check whether packages
  'libdbus-1-dev' and 'pkg-config' are installed:
  On Ubuntu:
  sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev pkg-config
  On Fedora:
  sudo dnf install dbus-devel pkgconf-pkg-config

  thread 'main' panicked at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/libdbus-sys-0.2.5/build.rs:25:9:
  explicit panic
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

So I tried checking if I was missing the libraries :

```
penwing@calcifer:~/Documents/projects/rust/susuwatari$ sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev pkg-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.2-1ubuntu3).
libdbus-1-dev is already the newest version (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Nope...
So I checked my PKG_CONFIG_PATH and it was empty, maybe that was it !
But even after getting a good path (which is kept even after restarting the terminal) :

```
penwing@calcifer:~/Documents/projects/rust/susuwatari$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/

penwing@calcifer:~/Documents/projects/rust/susuwatari$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
atk-bridge-2.0.pc  cairo-xlib-xrender.pc         gdk-pixbuf-2.0.pc         graphite2.pc            libbrotlienc.pc    libpng16.pc    pango.pc            xcursor.pc
atk.pc             datrie-0.2.pc                 gdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0.pc    grilo-plugins-0.3.pc    libcrypt.pc        libpng.pc      pangoxft.pc         xdamage.pc
atspi-2.pc         **dbus-1.pc**                     gdk-wayland-3.0.pc        gthread-2.0.pc          libdeflate.pc      libselinux.pc  pixman-1.pc         xdmcp.pc
blkid.pc           dbus-glib-1.pc                gdk-x11-3.0.pc            gtk+-3.0.pc             libffi.pc          libsepol.pc    pthread-stubs.pc    xext.pc
cairo-fc.pc        dleyna-connector-dbus-1.0.pc  geany.pc                  gtk+-broadway-3.0.pc    libglvnd.pc        libthai.pc     sm.pc               xfixes.pc
cairo-ft.pc        dleyna-server-service-1.0.pc  geoclue-2.0.pc            gtk+-unix-print-3.0.pc  libjpeg.pc         libtiff-4.pc   uuid.pc             xft.pc
cairo-gobject.pc   egl.pc                        gio-2.0.pc                gtk+-wayland-3.0.pc     liblzma.pc         libtirpc.pc    wayland-client.pc   xinerama.pc
cairo.pc           epoxy.pc                      gio-unix-2.0.pc           gtk+-x11-3.0.pc         libnsl.pc          libudev.pc     wayland-cursor.pc   xi.pc
cairo-pdf.pc       expat.pc                      glesv1_cm.pc              harfbuzz-gobject.pc     libpcre16.pc       libxcrypt.pc   wayland-egl.pc      xkbcommon.pc
cairo-png.pc       flatpak.pc                    glesv2.pc                 harfbuzz-icu.pc         libpcre2-16.pc     libxml-2.0.pc  wayland-scanner.pc  xorg-wacom.pc
cairo-ps.pc        fontconfig.pc                 glib-2.0.pc               harfbuzz.pc             libpcre2-32.pc     mount.pc       wayland-server.pc   xrandr.pc
cairo-script.pc    freetype2.pc                  gl.pc                     ice.pc                  libpcre2-8.pc      opengl.pc      x11.pc              xrender.pc
cairo-svg.pc       fribidi.pc                    glx.pc                    icu-i18n.pc             libpcre2-posix.pc  ostree-1.pc    xau.pc              xtst.pc
cairo-tee.pc       gcalc-2.pc                    gmodule-2.0.pc            icu-io.pc               libpcre32.pc       pangocairo.pc  xcb.pc              zlib.pc
cairo-xcb.pc       gci-1.pc                      gmodule-export-2.0.pc     icu-uc.pc               libpcrecpp.pc      pangofc.pc     xcb-render.pc
cairo-xcb-shm.pc   gdk-3.0.pc                    gmodule-no-export-2.0.pc  libbrotlicommon.pc      libpcre.pc         pangoft2.pc    xcb-shm.pc
cairo-xlib.pc      gdk-broadway-3.0.pc           gobject-2.0.pc            libbrotlidec.pc         libpcreposix.pc    pangoot.pc     xcomposite.pc
```

The dbus-1.pc is in the directory of the path, and yet, the error stayed the same

By looking around on the web I found similar issues resolved by installing libudev-dev (so I installed it as well)

Same thing for libdbus-glib-1-dev

I don't know what to do next.

And thank you if you had the courage to read up to here x)

Comment: When cross-compiling, you need the development packages _for your target,_ in your case for Windows. But `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` contains the library for the current host. Note however that DBus is pretty Linux-specific, so finding a Windows version may not be possible.

Comment: So, cross actually works with a docker container of the target environment and an emulation layer. If you need native libraries, you need to either extend the cross docker container (for your given arch/target) to install these libs, or use a custom container that has the libs you need, and the tool chain cargo needs. More info on the [cross GitHub page](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross)